# Verbs and actions in Dutch

Tags: localization, call-to-action

It's common to put verbs in buttons like "Delete" or "Edit", ... .
In English I know it's common practice to use the third-person verbs "Delete", "Edit", "Add", "Click here", ... but not the actual verbs themself "To delete".

But I noticed that in Dutch this is not always true. I've seen people use the word "Verwijderen", which is the verb itself (= to delete), but other people use "Verwijder", which is the imperative (we call it the "gebiedende wijs").

I see this quite often:

- Verberg/verbergen (to hide)
- Voeg toe/Toevoegen (to add)
- Verwijder/Verwijderen (to delete)

The worst of all is that it's quite mixed I think. For example, I've never seen someone use "Hier klikken" (= to click here), but most people use "Klik hier" (= click here).

But with the verb "Toevoegen" (= to add) it's less clear what to use, I've seen both cases ("Toevoegen" and "Voeg toe").

Comment: Since there’s no dutch.sx yet, this is probably on-topic here (or at linguistics.sx). The situation is actually quite similar in closely related German. There, the recommended solution is to use the infinite verb form which is **always** at the end of an action. This way, like with Dutch _toevoegen_, verbs aren’t split: _Füg X hinzu_ vs. _X hinzufügen_. That form is also less awkward if the object is omitted: _Hinzufügen_.

Comment: Off topic, but one of the other issues with localising in other languages is that the words are longer and don't fit on the buttons unless the font is shrunk...

Answer (score 2):

In English, the root form of the verb is also the imperative.  Thus, there is no choice between root form and imperative; they are the same thing.

On the other hand, in many other languages (including Dutch, I take it), the root form also functions as the infinitive.  It seems this introduces some ambiguity in terms of how one describes an action.  I could see either way:

- **Add** (imperative).  I am issuing an order to the program: *add!*
- **To add** (infinitive).  Click this button *to add*.

The latter would just be strange in English, because it involves adding an extra word.  You wouldn't want to have the word "to" on every button.

*Of course, another possibility is that some of the inconsistency in Dutch is due to people who are not fluent in Dutch translating the inferface.  Verb forms are one of the most difficult aspects of language.*

Comment: Yeah, in English it's quite clear to me that "To add" doesn't look well. But in Dutch the imperative and particple seems to be mixed in use. I think that in Dutch, when a verb in imperative has multiple words, the participle is often used.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion: "(To) add" is an infinitive form, not a participle. This would be "(has been) added". To make matters worse, many languages distinguish between the infinitive used with or without "to". So precisely speaking, the infinitive is just "add". English has identical forms for many different usages. The nice result: I agree to put "add" on the button, but because it is the infinitive. Sorry for being a linguist as well... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Judging from a German perspective, I think the infinitive form (what you called "actual verb", german "löschen", dutch "verwijderen") will work better than the imperative (german "Klicke hier", dutch "klik hier").

One issue is the separation of verbal prefixes (as in "voeg toe"), but for me, the more important issue is the question of who talks to whom: The imperative form suggests I am talking to the computer, issuing a command. To me, this often sounds awkward, maybe due to several factors: The rest of the screen text is not me talking to the computer, but rather vice versa, and I don't want to view the computer as someone (whom I can give commands to).

So I would always use the infinitive form, which is neutral in this respect.

Comment: I understand your point. But sometimes verbs are not pointed to the computer, but to the user, for example "Click here" (it's meant that the user should click there, not the computer I suppose). Does the same rule apply here? In Dutch that would mean that the label should say "Hier klikken" (the infinitive) in stead of "Klik hier" (the imperative). This sounds awkward as well.

Comment: @DimitriM I wouldn't use the imperative here, because I don't like to be pushed around (not even by humans :-). Also, there usually are several options - do you want to have "Click here" and "Click there" on the same screen? Which command to follow? I'd like to view these buttons/functions as offers to the user: "Click here to do this" and "Click there to do that". You can translate this with both imperative ("Klicke hier um dies zu tun") and infinitive ("Hier klicken um dies zu tun"), of course - I just think infinitive is more friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Verb forms like “delete” aren’t really third-person forms. They are just finite forms, which are used for a) present tense in all persons *except* third person singular (which is “deletes”) and b) imperative.

The use of the infinitive, which I have seen e.g. in German and Russian user interfaces, may be intentionally selected to avoid the nasty choice between two different imperative forms, one used between close friends and relatives, another used in other contexts as the more formal alternative. This avoids a choice between irritating people who feel the first form impolite and alienating them by using too formal an expression. English does not have such choices, since it lost a distinction between “thou” and “you” centuries ago.

Any verb can be used to give instructions, suggestions, or command. It is just a matter of convention. Oddly, in some cultures, the infinitive seems to be used as a “neutral” form in such contexts—not too friendly, but not markedly formal either.